# How to prevent countdown timer from resetting when the page refresh

Tags: javascript, timer

Hello Guys I'm having a problem. The countdown of my Page resets when the user refreshes the page. Is there a way to prevent it from resetting? like whoever goes to that specific page the timer will be how it used be on how I left it? not whoever goes to that page but for everyone who goes to that specific page just like the countdown timer in this site

playrps.net/

here is the code:

http://myanimesekai.com/countdown.js

Example:

http://myanimesekai.com/time.html

I've found a lot of question that is similar to this but no one have answered them yet..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save the start or end time for that user.

You can do that server-side if you are using php or the like but saving it to a session.

You can also do it client-side by saving it to a cookie or to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your counting down towards:

The page you mentioned uses an absolute time as the reference to calculate "count down":

`var someTargetDate = '07/09/2014 12:00:00';`

So every time someone loads the page, the counter value is calculated by something like:

```
var counterValue = Date.parse(someTargetDate) - Date.now();
```

However, if the target date is not known statically and can't be hardcoded in your HTML, for example, if you want to set the "targetDate" to be exactly a day from the first time a user goes to your webpage.
In this case, you need to set (and keep track of) targetDate in the users' sessions via either:

1. A backend server API which returns the `targetDate` OR
2. Browser-based stored (e.g. cookies)